# Arduino YUN: Serial Communication not working

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I have been unable to use the serial monitor with the Arduino YUN, I can download the compiled sketch with IDE 1.5.5 (on Windows XP via the USB connector that appears as COM6), the serial monitor opens but displays nothing. In order to investigate I modified the Blink example sketch as follows:

```
/*
Blink
Turns on an LED on for one second, then off for one second, repeatedly.

This example code is in the public domain.
*/

// Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards.
// give it a name:
int led = 13;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
// initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while  (!Serial) {;}
  Serial.println("Blink Program");
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  Serial.println("Blink Program -H");
  delay(5000);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  Serial.println("Blink Program -L");
  delay(5000);               // wait for a second
}
```

The sketch upoloads and runs, I see the LED blinking, it does not wait for SerialMonitor to open. The SerialMonitor displays nothing. I have noticed that during the upload COM6 disappers from the Windows device manager, a new port COM7 appears, the upload completes successfully, COM7 disappears and COM6 reappears.
I have also found that the YunSerialTerminal example is not working.
Do other people have successfully used the IDE 1.5.5 SerialMonitor on Windows XP?
Should I conclude that my Arduino Yun board is malfunctioning?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have in the mean time verified that serial communication works properly on Linux.

Comment: Serial Communication over USB also works properly in Linux running in VirtualBox hosred on the  Windows XP machine on which it fails.

Comment: did you solve your issue? Looks like it's happening the same here....

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: @ Sr.Richie, @meilon, I am sorry but I only saw your comments today. Personally I have come to the conclusion that it can not be done in XP, I reboot to Windows 7 (which occasionaly refuses to work and I have to reinstall the drivers) or Linux which works reliably. It might also have to do with XP service pack. I used SP2 at the time, I haven't tried with SP3

Comment: I record the following observation, it may be useful. I have faced the same problems with Leonardo, but it has recently started working. I am not sure what the reason is, but it may have to do with the installation of Windows XP Service Pack 3. The driver details are as follows (from Device Manager/Ports/Arduino Leonardo/Properties) Driver Provider Arduino LLC, Driver Date 15/11/2007, Driver Version 5.1.2600.0. In Driver Details Provider:Microsoft, File Version:5.1.2600.5512(xpsp.080413-2108). I can not say if this applies to YUN, as I do not have access to one at the time.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. A reset on 32U4 solved the problem (the button on the left top corner, next to the Ethernet connector). The serial port appeared on the arduino 1.5.x IDE and the connection was established and the data received.
Bridge and Console should be used when the selected port is the wifi one, not the real serial port.
I hope that helps.
Best,

Comment: This helps when I have some buggy code that locks up the Yun. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am running 1.5.5 and had a similar problem.  Console.begin() and Bridge.begin() work just fine.  Serial gives me nothing. I started with the following.

```
 void setup() {

  // for debugging, wait until a serial console is connected
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(4000);
  while(!Serial);

  Serial.print("Initializing the bridge...");
  Bridge.begin();
  Serial.println("Done");
}

void loop()
{
Serial.println("running...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your USB cable(needs to be USB data cable) and Port settings in Arduino IDE. Tools-->Port-->COM6(Arduino Yun).
This solved my problem in Windows.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by usb data cable? the one with 4 wires or someting else? For sure I used a 4 wire cable, the same one with XP, Linux and VBox.